# Mongo Ruby on Rails relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to mix 2 tutorials, and I'm failing at it. I am trying to create a users and microposts system with **rails** and **mongoid** for learning. I've run into a problem, since user id is no longer a basic number, and is instead handled by Mongo and it creates a random id, I think that the code cannot find out what microposts a user has, because a micropost thinks that the user_id is an Integer, not whatever the type of a mongo id is.

EDIT: Better explanation of problem: In short: I can't access the user ID from user or microposts, so even though each user has_many microposts, and each micropost belongs_to a user, it doesn't work because it has no idea what to do, where to go, and who is who.

I'm following this tutorial:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top

But I've changed a few things, I mixed it with this screen cast for MongoDB support: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid

So, in the section I'm reading (2.3.3 A user has_many microposts), you can see that each Micropost belongs to a user, and a user has many microposts. That seems fine, but when you keep going to where the author uses the console,  when I do it, it returns a blank array.

> 2.0.0p247 :008 > first_user = User.first
>
> MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin
>   command={:ismaster=>1} (0.4084ms)
>
> MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongo_app_development
>   collection=users selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}}
>   flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.2954ms)
>
> User _id: 522e6a7d1d41c86de5000001, name: "Namedude name", email: "thenamedman@gmail.com"> 
>   2.0.0p247 :009 > first_user.microposts
>
> MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongo_app_development
>   collection=microposts selector={"user_id"=>"522e6a7d1d41c86de5000001"}
>   flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3123ms)
>
> => []

I'm assuming that the problem is that the user_id field in Micropost is an Integer, and is not working with users? And user id's are called _id and look something like this: 522e6a7d1d41c86de5000001, is this just a regular old string? And would changing it to string do anything? I mean, how would it know what to look for? Please help, I'm completely new to Ruby, and I'm coming from Java (and not very good with that either).

EDIT: Just tried String and Mongo::ObjectID

String has the same result, and it makes a big deal about how it has no idea what an ObjectID is.

EDIT: Realizing now that it doesn't matter what the user_id is, because mongo has it's own object id, and I think I'm relying on that? But I cannot access that from the views, or any other models (microposts).

Comment: Maybe you should include some parts of your model definitions so people can see how things are set up. I just noticed the "mongoid" reference in your question so I updated the tags.

Comment: Moped::BSON::ObjectId? http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/bson.html